# Required "@" mark in email input field

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I just have one quick question, how do I check if my input contains some mark, like "@"?
I can submit my form under 5 conditions and one of them is that my email input has to contain "@" mark, but I can't find any info how to do this!

Comment: Have a look at regex validation. You will easily find many examples for email validation

Comment: A simple google search would give you a lot of info on this. If you only need @ and not complete e-mail validation look into for instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: When Googling "*is character in string javascript*" the **first** thing that came up was [`str.indexOf(char)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) - what did you search for since you didn't find this?

Comment: I'm new into JS, I've been coding for two weeks now.. not a native speaker of English , and I simply didn't know  how to put it into right words. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
inputValue.indexOf('@')
```

See here for more details

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp